# Kernel bypass possible with non-specialised NIC?

Tags: linux, network-adapter, kernel, linux-kernel, dma

Is it possible to perform kernel bypass and have a NIC send data to the user space (where I will write my network stack) with no copying, without having to purchase a specialised Solarflare etc NIC?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see `netmap(4)` manual page:

http://www.manualpages.de/FreeBSD/FreeBSD-8.3-RELEASE/man4/netmap.4.html

Linux also has netmap AFAIK.

http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/netmap/

Comment: The first link says: "netmap requires explicit support in device drivers"- which kinda suggests specialised hardware? I was actually going to write a device driver for a "normal" NIC (ie. one not like Solarflare).